# Connect VPN server to another VPN server

Tags: vpn

i have two ubuntu 20.04 server with different locations.

i installed OpenVPN in servers and i want connect server 1 to server 2. that's mean when i connect to server 1 by OpenVPN, my IP changes to server 2 IP.

get it ? server 1 get data from server 2 then send to me.

how to do it ?? Thanks.

Comment: That is not how VPN works or what it does.

Comment: i have to something like that. another solution? i'll accept.